# Trying to only return task without async/await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

```
    public async ValueTask<bool> AssetExistsForDeletion(int id, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return await fileDbContext.File.Where(x => x.Id == id
                        && x.ParentFileId == null
                        && x.IsDeleted == false)
                            .CountAsync(token) > 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

Can I somehow remove async/await from here while only returning task?

Comment: _"Can I somehow remove async/await from here while only returning task?"_ -- what do you mean? Given the code above, how could that even work? You (apparently) don't know whether to return `true` or `false` until the `CountAsync()` method has completed, _in the future_. What kind of task do you think exists in .NET that knows the future outcome before it happens? Somewhere, _something_ is going to have to await the `CountAsync()` and then produce the expected `true` or `false` value. And that's exactly what you have above.

Comment: Don't use `CountAsync()` and use a synchronous version, then return `Task`, but why would you want to return a `Task` from a synchronous method?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am trying check a if a condition is true and return bool without the use of async/await in the above while returning only task. I can substitute `.CountAsync()` with something else if that works

Comment: @RyanWilson I often build dictionaries of synchronous Tasks / Actions for command-based designs.

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul Since you want a boolean, why use `Count()` at all, why not `Any()` or `FirstOrDefault() != null`?

Comment: @RyanWilson yeah I can use `FirstOrDefault()` or `Any()` but that is irrelevant here, I am trying to figure out how I can do it without async/await while returning task

Comment: _"I am trying check a if a condition is true and return bool without the use of async/await in the above"_ -- but the value the condition depends on isn't available when the method is called. It will only become available in the future. It's certainly possible to construct and return a task object synchronously, but how would you know what to put in that object, until the original asynchronous task is done? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @RyanWilson: First of all, the syntax you suggest won't work. `Any()` returns a `bool` while your proposed method declaration requires a `ValueTask<bool>`. Second, it doesn't make sense to simply ignore the underlying asynchrony of the operation, _especially_ when the return type is a task object.

Comment: @RyanWilson I dont understand what you mean when you say wrapped in a `ValueTask`. While just trying to return `fileDbContext.File.Where(x => x.Id == id && x.ParentFileId == null && x.IsDeleted == false).Any();` after changing the method signature I am getting the cannot implicitly convert compile error.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Just spitballing here, but the reason *could* be because the OP is trying to implement an interface that specifies `ValueTask<bool>` as the return type, and the OP's specific scenario isn't actually asynchronous, the interface just allows for that to be a *possibility*.

Comment: @DanielMann: I understand you're just speculating, but... _"the OP's specific scenario isn't actually asynchronous"_ -- given the use of a database context and the call to `CountAsync()` instead of `Count()`, it seems almost certain that the underlying operation is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I'd probably just use `await` here, but if you think that there is a good chance that the downstream operation will often complete synchronously (perhaps because of caching), you can indeed avoid the `await`- here generalized

```cs
ValueTask<book> Foo()
{
    ValueTask<int> pending = yourAwaitableQueryHere; // ... blah.CountAsync(...);
    return pending.IsCompletedSuccessfully
        ? new(pending.Result > 0) : Awaited(pending);

    static async ValueTask<bool> Awaited(ValueTask<int> pending)
        => (await pending) > 0;
}
```

This completely bypasses the async machinery in the synchronous success case, while still working properly with incomplete async operations and exceptions.

You might also find that `.Count(predicate)` sometimes out-performs `.Where(predicate).Count()` (with or without async).

Comment: Is the _runtime_ overhead of a synchronously-completed `await` really so different from your proposal above to justify making it explicit? It would help if you could elaborate on why, if that's the case, given that `await` is _supposed_ to "do the right thing" when dealing with awaiting on already-completed tasks.

Comment: (There is also, of course, the problem that your proposal doesn't actually _eliminate_ the use of `async` and `await`, but rather simply defers it. It's not at all clear that that's what the OP is looking for.)

Comment: @PeterDuniho that is very contextual; in the case of LINQ that is going off-box, I would absolutely just use the `await`, as I hinted in the first line. But yes, this can make a huge difference - especially in library code doing things like, for example, socket/pipeline access and checking the result of an async operation like ReadAsync which is often synchronous. This is particularly noticeable when there are variables getting captured into a generated async state machine. This kind of change has been a small, but notable, part of the Kestrel performance improvements, for example.

Comment: @PeterDuniho re the second comment (I was probably replying at the time) : it avoids it in the case when it can be avoided. In the case that it can't be avoided: ***it can't be avoided*** (I know there's another answer using `ContinueWith`, but that's ultimately the same concept with a different API shape and semantics - using `ContinueWith` doesn't *usefully* avoid `await` - it just does an `await` in a different accent/flavor)

Answer (score -3):

`await` is nothing but syntactic sugar in the first place, so you can write the code explicitly yourself:

```
public ValueTask<bool> AssetExistsForDeletion(int id, CancellationToken token)
{
    return fileDbContext.File./* ... */CountAsync(token)
        .ContinueWith(t => t.Result > 0);
}
```

This will create and start the initial task as normal (your EF.Core query), then set up a continuation to return a result based on the result of the original task. Again, exactly the code `await` would generate.

Comment: _"exactly the code await would generate."_ -- not really. The above will fail to respect the current synchronization context, as well as fail to unwrap any exceptions, changing where they are observed. It also fails to take into account _why_ the OP wants to exclude `async` and `await` in the first place.

Comment: I couldn't even begin to guess why he wants to avoid them, but this code does indeed not use them, just (value) tasks. And there's no need for synchronization contexts because the continuation is a simple comparison and result return, it's in fact better than the original, broken code (it's missing a `.ConfiguraAwait(false)`).

Comment: Your point is taken though, it's not *exactly* the code generated by `await`, but it's close enough to generate the correct result.

Comment: Respectfully, it isn't a good idea to do this. `ContinueWith` should be considered deprecated in almost all scenarios, preferring `await`. Under the bonnet, the generated code here is quite different, and apart from other things: the framework is optimized for `await` now. Also, it looks like this could be `ValueTask<T>` based, which doesn't have this API.

Comment: Understood, but here we are in a question that wants to avoid `await`. At least this answer keeps the asynchronicity of EF.Core, unlike the other (deleted) answer.

Comment: There's a better way - I've added as an answer

Comment: This code doesn't function the same as the OP's.  While it's *possible* to use `ContinueWith` to accomplish what the code in this question does, this doesn't do that.